# Eliminar fila de datagridview con tecla suprimir?

Tags: c#, datagrid, visual, studio

Comunidad tengo un problema al borrar una fila del datagrid al presionar suprimir por defecto la borra la fina que le pido, pero quiero agregar un ciclo para para sumar una columna completa pero es hasta que borro por segunda vez que hace la sumatoria de la columna, ¿alguien cual es el problema?

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
        {
           
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {

                sumas += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
           
            }
            label10.Text = sumas.ToString();

        }
```

[image: en estas imágenes estoy eliminando filas]

Comment: Esta confusa su pregunta. Usted lo que quiere es Actualizar la sumatoria de las columnas luego de borrar o como? No se entiende bien, explicalo un poco mejor

Comment: quiero borrar una fila pero al borar no actualiza la sumatoria hasta que borro el segundo

Comment: Ahhh ok ahora sí

Comment: El datagrid tiene un evento que se llama RowsRemoved o algo así. En ese evento puede realizar lo que quiere luego de borrar la fila

Answer (score 0):

la solución que yo te doy es usando el evento KeyUp

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((int)e.KeyData == (int)Keys.Delete)
            {
                double piezas = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow ro in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    piezas += Convert.ToDouble(ro.Cells[0].Value);
                }
                textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(piezas);
                double total = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow ro2 in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    total += Convert.ToDouble(ro2.Cells[6].Value);
                }
                label7.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente _qué hace el código_: lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.